# Laravel 5.2 - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I got this error when i run edit method.

> Laravel 5.2 - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `q_alat` offset 0)

here is the controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Input;
use DB;
use Redirect;
use Auth;
use View;
use App\Alat;
use App\Jenis_alat;
use App\Plant;
use App\Departement;
use App\Workcenter;
use App\Cadangan_alat;
use App\Alat_baru;
use App\Request_nonaktif;
use App\Permohonan;
use App\file_standard;
use App\kategori;
use Response;

class Crudcontroller extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $data = DB::table('q_alat')->get();
        $jenis_alat = Jenis_alat::get();
        $departement = Departement::get();
        $plant = Plant::get();
        $workcenter = Workcenter::get();
        $kategori = kategori::get();
        $kalibrator = Alat::where('kategori','=','standard')->get();
        return view('akun/admin_0/alat/index')
        ->with('jenis_alat',$jenis_alat)
        ->with('q_alat',$data)
        ->with('departement',$departement)
        ->with('plant',$plant)
        ->with('workcenter',$workcenter)
        ->with('kategori',$kategori)
        ->with('kalibrator',$kalibrator)
        ->with('sort','1');
    }

public function search(Request $request){

    $query = $request->get('q');
    $hasil =DB::table('q_alat')->where('no_inventaris', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->paginate(10);

    return view('akun/admin_0/alat/result', compact('hasil', 'query'))
    ->with('sort','1')
    ->with('edit','');

}

public function page(){
    $page = session('alatPage');
    if ($page > 0) {
        
    }else{
        $page = 25;
    }
    $data = DB::table('q_alat')->paginate($page);
    $jenis_alat = Jenis_alat::get();
    $departement = Departement::get();
    $plant = Plant::get();
    $kategori = kategori::get();
    $workcenter = Workcenter::get();
    $kalibrator = Alat::where('kategori','=','standard')->get();
    return view('akun/admin_0/alat/index')
    ->with('jenis_alat',$jenis_alat)
    ->with('q_alat',$data)
    ->with('departement',$departement)
    ->with('plant',$plant)
    ->with('workcenter',$workcenter)
    ->with('kategori',$kategori)
    ->with('kalibrator',$kalibrator)
    ->with('page',$page)
    ->with('sort','1')
    ->with('edit','');
}

public function pilihPage(Request $request){
    session(['alatPage' => $request->input_page]);
    return redirect('/alat');
}

public function store(Request $request){
    $alat = new Alat;

    //buat variable dari inputan
    $get_jenis_alat = $request->input_jenis_alat;
    $get_no_urut = $request->input_no_urut;
    $get_departement = $request->input_departement;
    $get_plant = $request->input_plant;
    $get_tahun = $request->input_tahun;
    $get_workcenter = $request->input_workcenter;
    $get_kategori = $request->input_kategori;
    $get_merk = $request->input_merk;
    $get_no_seri = $request->input_no_seri;
    $get_no_asset = $request->input_no_asset;
    $get_tipe_alat = $request->input_tipe_alat;
    $get_durasi = $request->input_durasi;
    $get_tanggal_awal = $request->input_tanggal_awal;
    $get_jangkauan_pemakaian = $request->input_jangkauan_pemakaian;
    $get_kapasitas = $request->input_kapasitas;
    $get_resolusi = $request->input_resolusi;
    $get_kalibrator = $request->input_kalibrator;

    //buat kode alat
    $jenis = Jenis_alat::where('jenis_alat','=',$get_jenis_alat)->get();
    foreach ($jenis as $jenis1) {
        $kode_alat = $jenis1->kode_alat;    
    }

    //buat id departement
    $sql_departement =  Departement::where('nama_departement','=',$get_departement)->get();
    foreach ($sql_departement as $row) {
        $dept = $row->id_departement;
    }

    //buat id plant dan buat kode lokasi
    $sql_plant = Plant::where('nama_plant','=',$get_plant)->get();
    foreach ($sql_plant as $row) {
        $plant =  $row->id_plant;
    }
    if ($dept<10) {
        $dept1 = "0".$dept;
    }else{
        $dept1 = $dept;
    }
    $kode_lokasi = $dept1 ."". $plant ;

    //ambil tahun
    $tahun =$get_tahun;
    $tahun1 = substr($tahun, -2);

    //buat id workcenter
    $sql_get_workcenter = Workcenter::where('nama_workcenter','=',$get_workcenter)->get();
    foreach ($sql_get_workcenter as $row) {
        $get_workcenter = $row->id_workcenter;
    }

    //buat no urut
    $q_max = Alat::orderby('no_urut','desc')->where('kode_alat','=',$kode_alat)->where('kode_lokasi','=',$kode_lokasi)->first();
    // foreach ($q_max as $row) {
    //  $max1 = $row->no_urut;
    // }
    if ($q_max != '') {
        $max1 = $q_max->no_urut;
        $max2 = $max1 + 1;  
    }else{
        $max2 = 1;
    }
    $no_urut= $get_no_urut;
    if ($no_urut!="") {
        if ($no_urut < 10) {
            $no_urut1 = "00".$no_urut;
        }elseif ($no_urut < 100) {
            $no_urut1 = "0".$no_urut;
        }else{
            $no_urut1 = $no_urut;
        }   
    }else{
        if ($max2 < 10) {
            $no_urut1 = "00".$max2;
        }elseif ($max2 < 100) {
            $no_urut1 = "0".$max2;
        }else{
            $no_urut1 = $max2;
        }   
    }

    //cek duplikasi data dari inputan merk,tipe,nomor seri,nomor asset
    $cekDuplikat = Alat::where('merk_alat','=',$get_merk)->where('tipe_alat','=',$get_tipe_alat)->where('no_seri','=',$get_no_seri)->where('no_asset','=',$get_no_asset)->count();
    if ($cekDuplikat > 0) {
        return Redirect::to('/alat')->with('message','Merk alat, tipe alat, nomor seri, dan nomor asset sudah digunakan, silahkan masukan data lainnya!')->with('sort','1');
        //echo "<script>alert('Merk alat, tipe alat, nomor seri, dan nomor asset sudah digunakan, silahkan masukan data lainnya!');</script>";
    }else{

    //cek no urut
        if ($no_urut != "") {
            $cek_no_urut = Alat::where('no_urut','=',$no_urut)->where('kode_alat','=',$kode_alat)->where('kode_lokasi','=',$kode_lokasi)->count();
            if ($cek_no_urut > 0) {
                return Redirect::to('/alat')->with('message','No urut sudah digunakan, silahkan masukan nomor urut lainnya atau kosongkan!')->with('sort','1');
                //echo "<script>alert('No urut sudah digunakan, silahkan masukan nomor urut lainnya atau kosongkan!');</script>";
            }else{
            //generate no inventaris
                $table="tbl_alat";
                if ($get_kategori== "standard") {
                    $inventaris=$no_urut1."/".$kode_alat."-SK"."/".$kode_lokasi."/".$tahun1;
                }else{
                    $inventaris=$no_urut1."/".$kode_alat."/".$kode_lokasi."/".$tahun1;  
                }

            //insert
                $alat->no_inventaris = $inventaris;
                $alat->no_urut = $no_urut1;
                $alat->kode_alat = $kode_alat;
                $alat->kode_lokasi=$kode_lokasi;
                $alat->tahun = $tahun;
                $alat->merk_alat= $get_merk;
                $alat->no_seri= $get_no_seri;
                $alat->no_asset= $get_no_asset;
                $alat->kategori= $get_kategori;
                $alat->tipe_alat= $get_tipe_alat;
                $alat->id_workcenter= $get_workcenter;
                $alat->durasi= $get_durasi;
                $alat->tanggal_awal= $get_tanggal_awal;
                $alat->jangkauan_pemakaian= $get_jangkauan_pemakaian;
                $alat->kapasitas= $get_kapasitas;
                $alat->resolusi= $get_resolusi;
                $alat->kalibrator= $get_kalibrator;

                $alat->save();

                return Redirect::to('/alat')->with('message','Data alat berhasil diinput')->with('sort','1');
            }
        }else{
        //generate no inventaris
            $table="tbl_alat";
            if ($get_kategori== "standard") {
                $inventaris=$no_urut1."/".$kode_alat."-SK"."/".$kode_lokasi."/".$tahun1;
            }else{
                $inventaris=$no_urut1."/".$kode_alat."/".$kode_lokasi."/".$tahun1;  
            }

            //insert
            $alat->no_inventaris = $inventaris;
            $alat->no_urut = $no_urut1;
            $alat->kode_alat = $kode_alat;
            $alat->kode_lokasi=$kode_lokasi;
            $alat->tahun = $tahun;
            $alat->merk_alat= $get_merk;
            $alat->no_seri= $get_no_seri;
            $alat->no_asset= $get_no_asset;
            $alat->kategori= $get_kategori;
            $alat->tipe_alat= $get_tipe_alat;
            $alat->id_workcenter= $get_workcenter;
            $alat->durasi= $get_durasi;
            $alat->tanggal_awal= $get_tanggal_awal;
            $alat->jangkauan_pemakaian= $get_jangkauan_pemakaian;
            $alat->kapasitas= $get_kapasitas;
            $alat->resolusi= $get_resolusi;
            $alat->kalibrator= $get_kalibrator;

            $alat->save();

            return Redirect::to('/alat')->with('message','Data alat berhasil diinput')->with('sort','1');
        }
    }
}

public function edit($no1,$no2,$no3,$no4){
    $page = session('alatPage');
    $no_inventaris = $no1."/".$no2."/".$no3."/".$no4;
    $data = DB::table('q_alat')->paginate($page);
    $jenis_alat = Jenis_alat::get();
    $departement = Departement::get();
    $plant = Plant::get();
    $kategori = kategori::get();
    $workcenter = Workcenter::get();
    $kalibrator = Alat::where('kategori','=','standard')->get();
    $edit = DB::table('q_alat')->where('no_inventaris','=',$no_inventaris)->first();
    $get_kode = $edit->kode_lokasi;
    $id_plant = substr($get_kode, 2);
    $id_departement = substr($get_kode, 0,2);
    $edit_plant = Plant::where('id_plant','=',$id_plant)->first();
    $edit_departement = Departement::where('id_departement','=',$id_departement)->first();
    return view('/akun/admin_0/alat/index')
    ->with('jenis_alat',$jenis_alat)
    ->with('q_alat',$data)
    ->with('departement',$departement)
    ->with('plant',$plant)
    ->with('workcenter',$workcenter)
    ->with('kategori',$kategori)
    ->with('kalibrator',$kalibrator)
    ->with('edit_plant',$edit_plant)
    ->with('edit_departement',$edit_departement)
    ->with('edit',$edit)
    ->with('page',$page)
    ->with('sort','1');
    

    // $data = DB::table('q_alat')->paginate($page);
    // $jenis_alat = Jenis_alat::get();
    // $departement = Departement::get();
    // $plant = Plant::get();
    // $workcenter = Workcenter::get();
    // $kalibrator = Alat::where('kategori','=','standard')->get();
    // return view('akun/admin_0/alat/index')
    // ->with('jenis_alat',$jenis_alat)
    // ->with('q_alat',$data)
    // ->with('departement',$departement)
    // ->with('plant',$plant)
    // ->with('workcenter',$workcenter)
    // ->with('kalibrator',$kalibrator)
    // ->with('page',$page)
    // ->with('sort','1')
    // ->with('edits','');
}

public function update(Request $request){
    $alat = new Alat;

    //buat variable dari inputan
    $get_no_inventaris = $request->input_inventaris;
    $get_jenis_alat = $request->input_jenis_alat;
    $get_no_urut = $request->input_no_urut;
    $get_departement = $request->input_departement;
    $get_plant = $request->input_plant;
    $get_tahun = $request->input_tahun;
    $get_workcenter = $request->input_workcenter;
    $get_kategori = $request->input_kategori;
    $get_merk = $request->input_merk;
    $get_no_seri = $request->input_no_seri;
    $get_no_asset = $request->input_no_asset;
    $get_tipe_alat = $request->input_tipe_alat;
    $get_durasi = $request->input_durasi;
    $get_tanggal_awal = $request->input_tanggal_awal;
    $get_jangkauan_pemakaian = $request->input_jangkauan_pemakaian;
    $get_kapasitas = $request->input_kapasitas;
    $get_resolusi = $request->input_resolusi;
    $get_kalibrator = $request->input_kalibrator;

    //buat kode alat
    $jenis = Jenis_alat::where('jenis_alat','=',$get_jenis_alat)->get();
    foreach ($jenis as $jenis1) {
        $kode_alat = $jenis1->kode_alat;    
    }

    //buat id departement
    $sql_departement =  Departement::where('nama_departement','=',$get_departement)->get();
    foreach ($sql_departement as $row) {
        $dept = $row->id_departement;
    }

    //buat id plant dan buat kode lokasi
    $sql_plant = Plant::where('nama_plant','=',$get_plant)->get();
    foreach ($sql_plant as $row) {
        $plant =  $row->id_plant;
    }
    if ($dept<10) {
        $dept1 = "0".$dept;
    }else{
        $dept1 = $dept;
    }
    $kode_lokasi = $dept1 ."". $plant ;

    //ambil tahun
    $tahun =$get_tahun;
    $tahun1 = substr($tahun, -2);

    //buat id workcenter
    $sql_get_workcenter = Workcenter::where('nama_workcenter','=',$get_workcenter)->get();
    foreach ($sql_get_workcenter as $row) {
        $get_workcenter = $row->id_workcenter;
    }

    //buat no urut
    $q_max = Alat::orderby('no_urut','desc')->where('kode_alat','=',$kode_alat)->where('kode_lokasi','=',$kode_lokasi)->first();
    // foreach ($q_max as $row) {
    //  $max1 = $row->no_urut;
    // }
    if ($q_max != '') {
        $max1 = $q_max->no_urut;
        $max2 = $max1 + 1;  
    }else{
        $max2 = 1;
    }
    $no_urut= $get_no_urut;
    if ($no_urut!="") {
        if ($no_urut < 10) {
            $no_urut1 = "00".$no_urut;
        }elseif ($no_urut < 100) {
            $no_urut1 = "0".$no_urut;
        }else{
            $no_urut1 = $no_urut;
        }   
    }else{
        if ($max2 < 10) {
            $no_urut1 = "00".$max2;
        }elseif ($max2 < 100) {
            $no_urut1 = "0".$max2;
        }else{
            $no_urut1 = $max2;
        }   
    }

    $get_no_urut2 = Alat::where('no_inventaris','=',$get_no_inventaris)->first();
    $get_no_urut3 = $get_no_urut2->no_urut;

    //cek no urut
    if ($no_urut != "") {
        $cek_no_urut = Alat::where('no_urut','=',$no_urut)->where('no_urut','!=',$get_no_urut3)->where('kode_alat','=',$kode_alat)->where('kode_lokasi','=',$kode_lokasi)->count();
        if ($cek_no_urut > 0) {
            return Redirect('/alat')->with('sort','1');
            echo "<script>alert('No urut sudah digunakan, silahkan masukan nomor urut lainnya atau kosongkan!');</script>";
        }else{
            //generate no inventaris
            $table="tbl_alat";
            if ($get_kategori== "standard") {
                $inventaris=$no_urut1."/".$kode_alat."-SK"."/".$kode_lokasi."/".$tahun1;
            }else{
                $inventaris=$no_urut1."/".$kode_alat."/".$kode_lokasi."/".$tahun1;  
            }

            //update
            Alat::find($get_no_inventaris)->update([
                'no_inventaris'=> $inventaris,
                'no_urut'=> $no_urut1,
                'kode_alat'=> $kode_alat,
                'kode_lokasi'=>$kode_lokasi,
                'tahun'=> $tahun,
                'merk_alat'=> $get_merk,
                'no_seri'=> $get_no_seri,
                'no_asset'=> $get_no_asset,
                'kategori'=> $get_kategori,
                'tipe_alat'=> $get_tipe_alat,
                'id_workcenter'=> $get_workcenter,
                'durasi'=> $get_durasi,
                'tanggal_awal'=> $get_tanggal_awal,
                'jangkauan_pemakaian'=> $get_jangkauan_pemakaian,
                'kapasitas'=> $get_kapasitas,
                'resolusi'=> $get_resolusi,
                'kalibrator'=> $get_kalibrator
            ]);
            return Redirect::to('/alat')->with('message','Data berhasil diupdate')->with('sort','1');
        }
    }else{
        //generate no inventaris
        $table="tbl_alat";
        if ($get_kategori== "standard") {
            $inventaris=$no_urut1."/".$kode_alat."-SK"."/".$kode_lokasi."/".$tahun1;
        }else{
            $inventaris=$no_urut1."/".$kode_alat."/".$kode_lokasi."/".$tahun1;  
        }

            //insert
        Alat::find($get_no_inventaris)->update([
            'no_inventaris'=> $inventaris,
            'no_urut'=> $no_urut1,
            'kode_alat'=> $kode_alat,
            'kode_lokasi'=>$kode_lokasi,
            'tahun'=> $tahun,
            'merk_alat'=> $get_merk,
            'no_seri'=> $get_no_seri,
            'no_asset'=> $get_no_asset,
            'kategori'=> $get_kategori,
            'tipe_alat'=> $get_tipe_alat,
            'id_workcenter'=> $get_workcenter,
            'durasi'=> $get_durasi,
            'tanggal_awal'=> $get_tanggal_awal,
            'jangkauan_pemakaian'=> $get_jangkauan_pemakaian,
            'kapasitas'=> $get_kapasitas,
            'resolusi'=> $get_resolusi,
            'kalibrator'=> $get_kalibrator
        ]);
        return Redirect::to('/alat')->with('message','Data berhasil diupdate')->with('sort','1');
    }

}

public function delete($no1,$no2,$no3,$no4){
    $id = $no1."/".$no2."/".$no3."/".$no4;
    $get_alat = Alat::where('no_inventaris','=',$id)->first();
    Cadangan_alat::insert([
        'no_inventaris' => $id,
        'no_urut' => $get_alat->no_urut,
        'kode_alat' => $get_alat->kode_alat,
        'kode_lokasi' => $get_alat->kode_lokasi,
        'tahun' => $get_alat->tahun,
        'tipe_alat' => $get_alat->tipe_alat,
        'merk_alat' => $get_alat->merk_alat,
        'no_seri' => $get_alat->no_seri,
        'no_asset' => $get_alat->no_asset,
        'status' => $get_alat->status,
        'kategori' => $get_alat->kategori,
        'id_workcenter' => $get_alat->id_workcenter,
        'durasi' => $get_alat->durasi,
        'tanggal_awal' => $get_alat->tanggal_awal,
        'jangkauan_pemakaian' => $get_alat->jangkauan_pemakaian,
        'kapasitas' => $get_alat->kapasitas,
        'resolusi' => $get_alat->resolusi,
        'kalibrator' => $get_alat->kalibrator
    ]); 

    Alat::find($id)->delete();

    $data = DB::table('q_alat')->get();
    $jenis_alat = Jenis_alat::get();
    $departement = Departement::get();
    $plant = Plant::get();
    $workcenter = Workcenter::get();
    $kategori = kategori::get();
    $kalibrator = Alat::where('kategori','=','standard')->get();
    return Redirect('/alat')
    ->with('jenis_alat',$jenis_alat)
    ->with('q_alat',$data)
    ->with('departement',$departement)
    ->with('plant',$plant)
    ->with('workcenter',$workcenter)
    ->with('kategori',$kategori)
    ->with('kalibrator',$kalibrator)
    ->with('message','Data berhasil dihapus')
    ->with('sort','1'); 
}

public function sort($field,$by){
    if ($by == "asc") {
        $sort = "0";
    }else{
        $sort = "1";
    }
    $data = DB::table('q_alat')->orderBy($field,$by)->get();
    $jenis_alat = Jenis_alat::get();
    $departement = Departement::get();
    $plant = Plant::get();
    $workcenter = Workcenter::get();
    $kategori = kategori::get();
    $kalibrator = Alat::where('kategori','=','standard')->get();
    return view('akun/admin_0/alat/index')
    ->with('jenis_alat',$jenis_alat)
    ->with('q_alat',$data)
    ->with('departement',$departement)
    ->with('plant',$plant)
    ->with('workcenter',$workcenter)
    ->with('kategori',$kategori)
    ->with('kalibrator',$kalibrator)
    ->with('sort',$sort);
}

public function page_sort($field,$by){
    if ($by == "asc") {
        $sort = "0";
    }else{
        $sort = "1";
    }
    $page = session('alatPage');
    $data = DB::table('q_alat')->orderBy($field,$by)->paginate($page);
    $jenis_alat = Jenis_alat::get();
    $departement = Departement::get();
    $plant = Plant::get();
    $workcenter = Workcenter::get();
    $kategori = kategori::get();
    $kalibrator = Alat::where('kategori','=','standard')->get();
    return view('akun/admin_0/alat/index')
    ->with('jenis_alat',$jenis_alat)
    ->with('q_alat',$data)
    ->with('departement',$departement)
    ->with('plant',$plant)
    ->with('kategori',$kategori)
    ->with('workcenter',$workcenter)
    ->with('kalibrator',$kalibrator)
    ->with('page',$page)
    ->with('sort',$sort)
    ->with('edit','');
}

public function nonaktif(){
    $page = session('nonaktifPage');
    if ($page > 0) {
        
    }else{
        $page = 25;
    }
    $nonaktif = Cadangan_alat::select('no_inventaris','no_urut','kode_alat','kode_lokasi','tahun','tipe_alat','merk_alat','no_seri','no_asset','status','kategori','nama_workcenter','durasi','tanggal_awal','jangkauan_pemakaian','kapasitas','resolusi','kalibrator')->join('tbl_workcenter','tbl_alat_nonaktif.id_workcenter','=','tbl_workcenter.id_workcenter')->get();
    return view('akun/admin_0/cadangan')->with('alat_nonaktif',$nonaktif)->with('page',$page)->with('sort','1');
}
public function nonaktif_page(Request $request){
    session(['nonaktifPage' => $request->input_page]);
    return redirect('/alat_nonaktif');
}

public function sort_nonaktif($field,$by){
    if ($by == "asc") {
        $sort = "0";
    }else{
        $sort = "1";
    }
    $nonaktif = Cadangan_alat::select('no_inventaris','no_urut','kode_alat','kode_lokasi','tahun','tipe_alat','merk_alat','no_seri','no_asset','status','kategori','nama_workcenter','durasi','tanggal_awal','jangkauan_pemakaian','kapasitas','resolusi','kalibrator')->join('tbl_workcenter','tbl_alat_nonaktif.id_workcenter','=','tbl_workcenter.id_workcenter')->orderBy($field,$by)->get();
    return view('akun/admin_0/cadangan')->with('alat_nonaktif',$nonaktif)->with('sort',$sort);
}

public function delete_nonaktif($id1,$id2,$id3,$id4){
    $id = $id1."/".$id2."/".$id3."/".$id4;
    Cadangan_alat::find($id)->delete();
    $nonaktif = Cadangan_alat::select('no_inventaris','no_urut','kode_alat','kode_lokasi','tahun','tipe_alat','merk_alat','no_seri','no_asset','status','kategori','nama_workcenter','durasi','tanggal_awal','jangkauan_pemakaian','kapasitas','resolusi','kalibrator')->join('tbl_workcenter','tbl_alat_nonaktif.id_workcenter','=','tbl_workcenter.id_workcenter')->get();
    return Redirect('alat_nonaktif');
}

public function kembalikan($id1,$id2,$id3,$id4){
    $id = $id1."/".$id2."/".$id3."/".$id4;
    $get_alat = Cadangan_alat::where('no_inventaris','=',$id)->first();
    Alat::insert([
        'no_inventaris' => $id,
        'no_urut' => $get_alat->no_urut,
        'kode_alat' => $get_alat->kode_alat,
        'kode_lokasi' => $get_alat->kode_lokasi,
        'tahun' => $get_alat->tahun,
        'tipe_alat' => $get_alat->tipe_alat,
        'merk_alat' => $get_alat->merk_alat,
        'no_seri' => $get_alat->no_seri,
        'no_asset' => $get_alat->no_asset,
        'status' => $get_alat->status,
        'kategori' => $get_alat->kategori,
        'id_workcenter' => $get_alat->id_workcenter,
        'durasi' => $get_alat->durasi,
        'tanggal_awal' => $get_alat->tanggal_awal,
        'jangkauan_pemakaian' => $get_alat->jangkauan_pemakaian,
        'kapasitas' => $get_alat->kapasitas,
        'resolusi' => $get_alat->resolusi,
        'kalibrator' => $get_alat->kalibrator
    ]);

    Cadangan_alat::find($id)->delete();
    return Redirect('alat_nonaktif');
}

public function alat_baru(){
    $jenis_alat = Jenis_alat::get();
    $departement = Departement::get();
    $plant = Plant::get();
    $workcenter = Workcenter::get();
    $kalibrator = Alat::where('kategori','=','standard')->get();
    $data = DB::table('q_alat_baru')->get();
    return view('akun/admin_0/alat_baru')
    ->with('alat',$data)
    ->with('jenis_alat',$jenis_alat)
    ->with('departement',$departement)
    ->with('plant',$plant)
    ->with('workcenter',$workcenter)
    ->with('kalibrator',$kalibrator)
    ->with('cek_edit','0')
    ->with('tampil','0');
}

public function alat_baru_page(){
    $page = session('alatBaruPage');
    if ($page > 0) {
        
    }else{
        $page = 15;
    }
    $jenis_alat = Jenis_alat::get();
    $departement = Departement::get();
    $plant = Plant::get();
    $workcenter = Workcenter::get();
    $kalibrator = Alat::where('kategori','=','standard')->get();
    $data = DB::table('q_alat_baru')->paginate($page);
    return view('akun/admin_0/alat_baru')
    ->with('alat',$data)
    ->with('jenis_alat',$jenis_alat)
    ->with('departement',$departement)
    ->with('plant',$plant)
    ->with('workcenter',$workcenter)
    ->with('kalibrator',$kalibrator)
    ->with('cek_edit','0')
    ->with('tampil','0');
}

public function input_alat_baru($id){
    $jenis_alat = Jenis_alat::get();
    $departement = Departement::get();
    $plant = Plant::get();
    $workcenter = Workcenter::get();
    $kalibrator = Alat::where('kategori','=','standard')->get();
    $data = DB::table('q_alat_baru')->get();
    $edit = DB::table('q_alat_baru')->where('id_alat_baru','=',$id)->first();
    $get_kode = $edit->kode_lokasi;
    $id_plant = substr($get_kode, 2);
    $id_departement = substr($get_kode, 0,2);
    $edit_plant = Plant::where('id_plant','=',$id_plant)->first();
    $edit_departement = Departement::where('id_departement','=',$id_departement)->first();
    return view('akun/admin_0/alat_baru')
    ->with('alat',$data)
    ->with('jenis_alat',$jenis_alat)
    ->with('departement',$departement)
    ->with('plant',$plant)
    ->with('workcenter',$workcenter)
    ->with('kalibrator',$kalibrator)
    ->with('edit',$edit)
    ->with('cek_edit','1')
    ->with('edit_plant',$edit_plant)
    ->with('edit_departement',$edit_departement)
    ->with('tampil','1');
}

public function input_alat_baru_input(Request $request,$id){
    $get_jenis_alat = $request->input_jenis_alat;
    $get_no_urut = $request->input_no_urut;
    $get_departement = $request->input_departement;
    $get_plant = $request->input_plant;
    $get_tahun = $request->input_tahun;
    $get_workcenter = $request->input_workcenter;
    $get_kategori = $request->input_kategori;
    $get_merk = $request->input_merk;
    $get_no_seri = $request->input_no_seri;
    $get_no_asset = $request->input_no_asset;
    $get_tipe_alat = $request->input_tipe_alat;
    $get_durasi = $request->input_durasi;
    $get_tanggal_awal = $request->input_tanggal_awal;
    $get_jangkauan_pemakaian = $request->input_jangkauan_pemakaian;
    $get_kapasitas = $request->input_kapasitas;
    $get_resolusi = $request->input_resolusi;
    $get_kalibrator = $request->input_kalibrator;

    //buat kode alat
    $jenis = Jenis_alat::where('jenis_alat','=',$get_jenis_alat)->get();
    foreach ($jenis as $jenis1) {
        $kode_alat = $jenis1->kode_alat;    
    }

    //buat id departement
    $sql_departement =  Departement::where('nama_departement','=',$get_departement)->get();
    foreach ($sql_departement as $row) {
        $dept = $row->id_departement;
    }

    //buat id plant dan buat kode lokasi
    $sql_plant = Plant::where('nama_plant','=',$get_plant)->get();
    foreach ($sql_plant as $row) {
        $plant =  $row->id_plant;
    }
    if ($dept<10) {
        $dept1 = "0".$dept;
    }else{
        $dept1 = $dept;
    }
    $kode_lokasi = $dept1 ."". $plant ;

    //ambil tahun
    $tahun =$get_tahun;
    $tahun1 = substr($tahun, -2);

    //buat id workcenter
    $sql_get_workcenter = Workcenter::where('nama_workcenter','=',$get_workcenter)->get();
    foreach ($sql_get_workcenter as $row) {
        $get_workcenter = $row->id_workcenter;
    }

    //buat no urut
    $q_max = Alat::orderby('no_urut','desc')->where('kode_alat','=',$kode_alat)->where('kode_lokasi','=',$kode_lokasi)->first();
    // foreach ($q_max as $row) {
    //  $max1 = $row->no_urut;
    // }
    if ($q_max != '') {
        $max1 = $q_max->no_urut;
        $max2 = $max1 + 1;  
    }else{
        $max2 = 1;
    }
    $no_urut= $get_no_urut;
    if ($no_urut!="") {
        if ($no_urut < 10) {
            $no_urut1 = "00".$no_urut;
        }elseif ($no_urut < 100) {
            $no_urut1 = "0".$no_urut;
        }else{
            $no_urut1 = $no_urut;
        }   
    }else{
        if ($max2 < 10) {
            $no_urut1 = "00".$max2;
        }elseif ($max2 < 100) {
            $no_urut1 = "0".$max2;
        }else{
            $no_urut1 = $max2;
        }   
    }

    //cek no urut
    if ($no_urut != "") {
        $cek_no_urut = Alat::where('no_urut','=',$no_urut)->where('no_urut','!=',$get_no_urut3)->where('kode_alat','=',$kode_alat)->where('kode_lokasi','=',$kode_lokasi)->count();
        if ($cek_no_urut > 0) {
            return Redirect('/alat')->with('sort','1');
            echo "<script>alert('No urut sudah digunakan, silahkan masukan nomor urut lainnya atau kosongkan!');</script>";
        }else{
            //generate no inventaris
            $table="tbl_alat";
            if ($get_kategori== "standard") {
                $inventaris=$no_urut1."/".$kode_alat."-SK"."/".$kode_lokasi."/".$tahun1;
            }else{
                $inventaris=$no_urut1."/".$kode_alat."/".$kode_lokasi."/".$tahun1;  
            }
        }
    }else{
        //generate no inventaris
        $table="tbl_alat";
        if ($get_kategori== "standard") {
            $inventaris=$no_urut1."/".$kode_alat."-SK"."/".$kode_lokasi."/".$tahun1;
        }else{
            $inventaris=$no_urut1."/".$kode_alat."/".$kode_lokasi."/".$tahun1;  
        }
    }


    Alat::insert([
        'no_inventaris'=> $inventaris,
        'no_urut'=> $no_urut1,
        'kode_alat'=> $kode_alat,
        'kode_lokasi'=>$kode_lokasi,
        'tahun'=> $tahun,
        'merk_alat'=> $get_merk,
        'no_seri'=> $get_no_seri,
        'no_asset'=> $get_no_asset,
        'kategori'=> $get_kategori,
        'tipe_alat'=> $get_tipe_alat,
        'id_workcenter'=> $get_workcenter,
        'durasi'=> $get_durasi,
        'tanggal_awal'=> $get_tanggal_awal,
        'jangkauan_pemakaian'=> $get_jangkauan_pemakaian,
        'kapasitas'=> $get_kapasitas,
        'resolusi'=> $get_resolusi,
        'kalibrator'=> $get_kalibrator
    ]);

    $edit = DB::table('q_alat_baru')->where('id_alat_baru','=',$id)->first();
    $get_kode = $edit->kode_lokasi;

    Alat_baru::find($id)->delete();


    $jenis_alat = Jenis_alat::get();
    $departement = Departement::get();
    $plant = Plant::get();
    $workcenter = Workcenter::get();
    $kalibrator = Alat::where('kategori','=','standard')->get();
    $data = DB::table('q_alat_baru')->get();
    $id_plant = substr($get_kode, 2);
    $id_departement = substr($get_kode, 0,2);
    $edit_plant = Plant::where('id_plant','=',$id_plant)->first();
    $edit_departement = Departement::where('id_departement','=',$id_departement)->first();
    return view('akun/admin_0/alat_baru')
    ->with('alat',$data)
    ->with('jenis_alat',$jenis_alat)
    ->with('departement',$departement)
    ->with('plant',$plant)
    ->with('workcenter',$workcenter)
    ->with('kalibrator',$kalibrator)
    ->with('edit',$edit)
    ->with('cek_edit','0')
    ->with('edit_plant',$edit_plant)
    ->with('edit_departement',$edit_departement)
    ->with('tampil','0')
    ->with('message','alat berhasil diinput');
}
```

}

here is the route:

```
Route::post('alat/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}/{id4}/edit', 'Crudcontroller@edit')->middleware('admin_petugas');
```

please help me, thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO ... does `$page` actually have a value? the first argument to `paginate` is the amount of records you want per page

Comment: yes, it have a value

Comment: can i just send the method of the page? or i just send all the code on controller? sorry for my bad english and this is my first time asking in stack overflow

Comment: i already edit my question, i'm using laravel version 5.2 , this is not my project actually, i just continuing the project

Comment: you should be able to use the stacktrace to find which line is doing the query that is causing the error ... we don't need to see every method, only the one that has the query throwing the error ... but what is the value of this `$page` variable in the `edit` method?

Comment: the value is depends on how much $page on the index.blade.php, you can choose the value on the index but the default is 25

Comment: i think the error was not the paginate, cuz it works fine, i only get this error when i clicked edit button in the index.blade.php, the edit button is running the edit method

Comment: the edit method has a pagination query in it ... the 3rd line of that method (if you pass an odd value to `paginate` it could create that exact query you are seeing in the error) ... but use the stack trace to find out what line is causing the error

Comment: okay, i'll try it, thank you so much

Comment: so in the `edit` method make sure that `$page` is a positive number (`dd($page);`), still trying to rule out the `paginate` call

Comment: this problem is solved, thanks